# What are all those different localhost domains that apps connect to?

Tags: privacy, data-monitoring, hosts

I'm using the Blokada adblocker on my phone, which acts as a vpn and can show me all the domains that apps request to connect to and let me switch them between an accept list and a deny list. Whenever I install an app with known trackers, I try to block as many of those domains as possible while keeping the base functionality of the app.

I noticed that my log has about a hundred of domains with localhost in the name, many of them not even looking like a url. For example, among some that my phone tried to contact hundreds on times:

```
localhost_name
localhost0#3}
localhostfo
localhostz\012({
localhostsys
localhost_code
localhostdn.com
localhostgs
localhostsysu
localhostms
localhostal.org
localhostp.net
localhostde
localhostt.com
localhost.com
localhostx.com
localhostahn.de
localhoste.com
localhost=tun0
```

Some look like actual domain urls accessible on the internet, some not. Some have those weird special characters in them. What are they? Actual domains? Or are they pointing to a webserver running on my phone like normal `localhost` would? Why are there so many of them?

My instinct was to block them on sight because I don't want apps to keep track of my phone connecting to their servers from different IPs, effectively mapping out everywhere I'm going. And I have a hard time trusting a domain name looking like "localhostz\012({". Is there a reason I shouldn't block them?

Comment: Looks like a bad log. As the developer of the app.

Comment: I saw this behaviour on startup by many apps - `com.driveby.app`, `de.hafas.android.db` etc. You see the lookups within IP packets to google endpoints, my guess it's either Google CrashLytics or Firebase Analytics